# How to work around AngularJS Directive with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I have the following script with `dateTimePicker` as a AngularJS directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('feedApp');

    module.directive('datetimepicker', [
        '$timeout',
        function ($timeout) {
            return {
                require: '?ngModel',
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    options: '@',
                    onChange: '&',
                    onClick: '&'
                },
                link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
                    $($element).on('dp.change', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            var dtp = $($element).data('DateTimePicker');
                            controller.$setViewValue(dtp.date().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'));
                            $scope.onChange();
                        });
                    });

                    $($element).on('click', function () {
                        $scope.onClick();
                    });

                    controller.$render = function () {
                        if (!!controller) {
                            if (controller.$viewValue === undefined) {
                                controller.$viewValue = null;
                            }
                            else if (!(controller.$viewValue instanceof moment)) {
                                controller.$viewValue = moment(controller.$viewValue);
                            }
                            $($element).data('DateTimePicker').date(controller.$viewValue);
                        }
                    };

                    $($element).datetimepicker($scope.$eval($attrs.options));
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

And I want to rewrite it using TypeScript. This is the code I have for now:

```
namespace feedApp {
    'use strict';

    DateTimePicker.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function DateTimePicker($timeout: ng.ITimeoutService): ng.IDirective {
        var directive = <ng.IDirective>{
            require: '?ngModel',
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                options: '@',
                onChange: '&',
                onClick: '&'
            },
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope: ng.IScope, element: JQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, controller: ng.INgModelController): void {
            $(element).on('dp.change', function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    var dtp = $(element).data('DateTimePicker');
                    controller.$setViewValue(dtp.date().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'));
                    scope.onChange();
                });
            });

            $(element).on('click', function () {
                scope.onClick();
            });

            controller.$render = function () {
                if (!!controller) {
                    if (controller.$viewValue === undefined) {
                        controller.$viewValue = null;
                    }
                    else if (!(controller.$viewValue instanceof moment)) {
                        controller.$viewValue = moment(controller.$viewValue);
                    }
                    $(element).data('DateTimePicker').date(controller.$viewValue);
                }
            };

            $(element).datetimepicker(scope.$eval(attrs.options));
        }

        return directive;
}

angular.module("feedApp")
    .directive("datetimepicker", DateTimePicker);
```

}

I'm not experienced with TypeScript and I don't really know what is the best practise to change jQuery elements like `$(element).on` using TS. How to work with

```
    scope: {
        options: '@',
        onChange: '&',
        onClick: '&'
    },
```

inside TypeScript `link` function? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What's the rationale behind using jQuery for things like 'click' in your directive? Also I never seen things like $($element) so what's the thinking behind that? I'm just curious. No offence :)

Comment: The `$($element)` is completely redundant: angular elements are already wrapped in jqLite (or jquery if you have loaded it) so everything using `$($element)` could be more simply written as `$element`.

Comment: The first example wrote in JS is taken from the internet and it works. `$($element)` (if I understand it well enough) is just pointing the HTML element so You can use events like `.on` etc.

Comment: @Duncan it was not working for me this way, but I don't have the jqLite. Is there any need to use it in TypeScript too ? Thanks for the advice

Comment: jqlite is included as part of angular, it provides a subset of jQuery on anything wrapped in `angular.element` which includes the `$element` passed to the directive and is used unless you specifically load jquery. It might not work though if you loaded angular first and then loaded jquery because angular would be wrapping in jqlite when you want jquery. Typescript won't affect whether or not you need to use jquery.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply @Duncan . I will try that. Maybe You know how to use a scope: { options: '@' ...} element in trypescript ? I don't really understand what this `scope.onChange();` , `scope.onClick();` and `attrs.options` do and TS is not compiling because of them. I can't access the scope object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bindToController to access scope variables inside directive controller.
For better structuring/understanding please declare different components of  a directive in different files like controller should be in an unique file, html should have its own file etc.

Please refer [Directive testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895268/unit-testing-typescript-directive-template-karma-jasmine-html-is-not-defined) question and [typescript github sample project](https://github.com/comsysto/angular-architecture) for more info regarding it.

If you required more clarification, please do tell me.

Regards

Ajay

Comment: Nice examples ! :) Thank you for your answear. It's hard to find something valuable about angular + ts on the internet. This helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Marox Refer https://medium.com/@bojzi/anatomy-of-a-large-angular-application-f098e5e36994#.dgmais72c for more help. Blog of same github repository. Thanks.:-)