# Angular Can't Inject Custom Service when Unit Testing Directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, typescript

I am trying to test directives and I have looked at a couple examples but I can't find one similar to mine.  My current problem is that I have a controller attached to my directive and Angular can't seem to find my custom services which are injected into the controller but it can find it's own services.

**Directive**

```
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    constructor(private clientAppState: IClientAppState) { }
        static instance(clientAppState: IClientAppState): ng.IDirective {
            return new LocationAccessCodeDirective(clientAppState);
        }

    restrict = 'E';
    templateUrl = 'myDirectiveDirectory.html';
    controller = MyDirectiveController;
    controllerAs = 'myDirectiveController';
    scope: {};
}

angular
.module('myDirective')
.directive('myDirectiveName', MyDirective.instance);
```

**MyDirectiveController**

```
export class MyDirectiveController implements ILocationAccessCodeScope {

    constructor(protected $analytics: angulartics.IAnalyticsService,
                public errorMessageService: IErrorMessageService //Custom Service
                ) 
    {
        //Initializations
    }
```

**Dependency File**

```
MyDirectiveController.$inject = [
    '$analytics',
    'ErrorMessageService',
];
```

**Spec**

```
describe("myDirective", () => {

    var scope;

    beforeEach(() => {
        angular.mock.module(
            'DirectiveModule',
            'ServiceModule',
            'ng',
            'myDirectiveDirectory.html'
        );

        mockErrorMessageService = sinon.stub(new MockErrorMessageService());

        angular.mock.module(($provide): void => {
            $provide.value('ErrorMessageService', mockErrorMessageService);
        });

        inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {

            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            var element = angular.element("<directive-tag></directive-tag>");
            var comEl = $compile(element)(scope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            console.log(element[0].outerHTML);
            //Note that if I remove the (scope)
            //...from $compile(element)(scope)
            //my directive is printed out
        });
    });

    describe('first directive test', () => {
        it('first it', () => {
            console.log("it");
        });
    });
});
```

**Error Message**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ErrorMessageServiceProvider <- errorMessageService
```

For some reason Angular injects its own Analytics service into my controller but it cannot find my own service and I can't seem to figure out why, and I'm pretty sure I have included all of the relevant files into my **Karma.config.js** file

Also note, this may be irrelevant but I tried inject a random custom service into an **beforeEach** block and I got the same error, but when injecting it using inline annotation it found the service, I'm not sure why this may be because I'm not minifying my code, and as you can see from the dependency list it is also being inject as a list.

Comment: you should create a mock ErrorMessageService and inject it in test file. for more info refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895268/unit-testing-typescript-directive-template-karma-jasmine-html-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was including my dependency file after my controller file, but for some reason it started working when I included my dependency file first.